# Souped links mysteriously shortened?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I've been souping and subsequently requesting a bunch of links from google and I've just encountered some really weird behaviour for the first time.

The google source page has links with this structure: `<cite class="iUh30">www.kraso.sk/wp-
content/uploads/sutaze/2015_2016/20151001_ont/</cite>`

The URL above is the one causing me issues. I run this simple snippet:

```
r = request_url(url=search, on_failure=None) # just applies .get() & handles errors
html = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
all_links = html.find_all("cite")


for link in all_links:
    logger.info(f"Examining link {link.text} for {db_event_name} {search_year}")
    logger.info(f"Is 2016 in {link.text}? {'2016' in link.text}")
```

and get the following log, as well as a 404 Error when I try to request the link (which works just fine when visited through the browser):

```
2018-08-24 15:38:23 - __main__ - INFO  - Examining link www.kraso.sk/wp-content/uploads/sutaze/2015.../20151001_ont/ for Nepela 2015
2018-08-24 15:38:23 - __main__ - INFO  - Is 2016 in www.kraso.sk/wp-content/uploads/sutaze/2015.../20151001_ont/? False
```

The test (is 2016 in link) should come back positive as the full link contains it. This seems to mean the "2015.../" section in the logs is in fact not an abbreviation for formatting purposes, but that the "_2016" has in fact been replaced by "..." - confirmed this by comparing print to log, logging into a file instead of to console, etc.

Has anyone seen this before or know how to handle? Thanks!